# Error while opening a simple text file

Tags: vbscript

I have this below code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO, logfolder, ManualFile2, ManualCopyFiles, checkfile
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
logfolder = "C:\Users\TEMPPAHIR\LearnVB\Logfolder\"
ManualFile2 = objFSO.BuildPath(logfolder, "ManualFoldListReq.txt")
If objFSO.FileExists(ManualFile2) Then
    Set checkfile = objFSO.GetFile(ManualFile2) 
    If checkfile.Size > 0 Then
        Set ManualCopyFiles = objFSO.OpenTextFile(ManualFile2)
        Wscript.echo "error number is : " & Err.number
        Wscript.echo " File size is greater than zero "
    Else
        Wscript.echo " File size is zero "
    End IF
Else
    Wscript.echo " File does not exists " 
End If
```

When I run this script it works fine. But when I put this piece of code inside my 500 lines of big VBScript, it is giving me an error on the line

```
Set ManualCopyFiles = objFSO.OpenTextFile(ManualFile2)
```

like below. I have written a sub which throws error into a logfile in the below format.

```
2015-12-28 17:27:08 -   Error Number: 451
2015-12-28 17:27:08 -   Error (Hex): 1C3
2015-12-28 17:27:08 -   Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error
2015-12-28 17:27:08 -   Description: Object not a collection
2015-12-28 17:27:08 -   Other Information: Error opening file: ManualFoldListReq.txt
```

What is surprising is that the same piece of code is not working when it's a part of big script. Can anyone please help me to locate what exactly is going wrong here?

Comment: Your working code snippet doesn't contain operations on a collection. Please reduce your non-working code to a self-contained sample that still demonstrates the problem and post that.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - That's the catch.. My non-working code is exactly the same as the working code which I have specified above. Just I copy paste the code in another script and it starts throwing the error.

Comment: I already told you what you need to do. We can't help you solve the problem if we can't reproduce it.

Comment: Is there a way I can attach my entire script here? Because even I am not able to reproduce the error in a small sample piece as explained in the main question it works fine when I try to run it individually.

Comment: You could use http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Perhaps you should add Error check lines every now and then? I do hope you have break your code into Subs and Functions so you can add something like `Wscript.Echo "End of SubName()"` to end of each Sub/Function to narrow down the error line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you inserting this line in the above code block?  It's not used at all in your example.

```
Set ManualCopyFiles = objFSO.OpenTextFile(ManualFile2)
```

If there is a purpose for using the file, then please show it.

If that use follows the `.GetFile` method then you can use the `.OpenAsTextStream` method to open the file for Read/Write/or Append.

Here, this is simpler and uses more standard names for vars.  Try it.

```
Option Explicit
Dim FSO, objFile, strLogFolder, strManualFile2

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

strLogFolder = "C:\Users\TEMPPAHIR\LearnVB\Logfolder\"
strManualFile2 = strLogFolder & "ManualFoldListReq.txt"

If FSO.FileExists(strManualFile2) Then
    Set objFile = FSO.GetFile(strManualFile2) 
    If objFile.Size > 0 Then
        'Parameters ref  http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/14044
        objFile.OpenAsTextStream(1,-2)
        '... there should not be an error here
        Wscript.echo "error number is : " & Err.number
        Wscript.echo " File size is greater than zero "
    Else
        Wscript.echo " File size is zero "
    End IF
Else
    Wscript.echo " File does not exists " 
End If
```